# Specifying today's date in an xml file

Tags: xml, scheduled-tasks, utf-16, windows-task-scheduler

I am new to XML files in general and need help in getting today's date put into my file to import into Task Scheduler. I exported a task that I will need to run on several computers in the near future, but it keeps a static time of the initial time I scheduled it to run. I am looking to have the file enter today's date when being imported into Task Scheduler. I am currently just opening this using notepad to view the data, and if I can edit it there that would be great or if need another program to edit it let me know. I looked online and found a couple of posts here which seemed to be similar, but I could not figure out how to alter it for my needs.

Shown below is the start of the file, which includes the part where the date I would like to have be dynamic is, under the "StartBoundary" section. As stated, I know little to nothing about XML files, so please explain it to me simply as possible, and as if I know nothing (which is not too far off). If you need more info let me know.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
<RegistrationInfo>
<Date>2018-02-20T11:22:05.1529214</Date>
<Author>me</Author>
<URI>my task</URI>
</RegistrationInfo>
<Triggers>
<TimeTrigger>
  <StartBoundary>2018-2-20T16:15:00</StartBoundary>
  <Enabled>true</Enabled>
</TimeTrigger>
</Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering because I had the same question.
I ended up creating an XML with a static date, then running this from the command prompt:

```
schtasks /create /xml c:\test\test.xml /tn TaskName /f

schtasks /tn TaskName /change /sd %date%
```

Basically, create from XML then change the start date.
My script has a delay of 365 days, run asap if missed, so I get a program run a year from now.

Works in UK as DD/MM/YYYY